# Sencha Touch 2.X Workaround for HTC One Phones

Tags: android, sencha-touch

Ext version tested:
    Sencha Touch 2.2

Browser versions tested against:
    Chrome on HTC One (Android 4.1.2)
    Stock HTC One Browser (Android 4.1.2)

Description:
    Sencha Messageboxes and the like won't release focus after clearing them in the stock browser or webviews on an HTC One.
    This problem doesn't happen on Chrome or on other Android 4.1.2 phones AFAIK.  Tested a Samsung today and all worked as expected.

Steps to reproduce the problem:
    Using an HTC One, go to the Sencha Kitchen Sink demo here:  http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/overlays
    Tap on 'Alert', and then 'OK'.  Works fine in Chrome.  Does not work in either stock browser or in a webview (so no PhoneGap/Cordova either).

Yes, I know, this belongs on a Sencha board.  I posted a thread there this weekend, and the post was deleted Monday morning.  Google 'sencha default overlays Android 4.1.2 HTC One' to see a dead link.  So I'm posting here.

Perhaps my frustration was showing and Sencha didn't like the tone of my post.  I really would like to see some kind of workaround from either Sencha, HTC or someone here on SO.

Does anyone know of a software workaround that will allow Sencha Touch 2.X to work on an HTC One?  Or are we stuck waiting on HTC and the carriers?  Not really Sencha's fault, but this leaves me down on HTML-5 mobile app development.

Comment: actually all my apps so far have worked perfectly on HTC One. And I can't seem to replicate the issue either. Do you have a rooted device ? or a custom browser or something else that could be causing this error ? Have you tested this on any other devices ?

Comment: I had a standard HTC One from Sprint.  I've also verified on a friends AT&T One. Sencha has classifed this as a bug, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that HTC messed with the Android stock browser enough to mess things up.  So you don't see a problem when you go to the Sencha examples site in the stock browser and show an overlay?  Who is your carrier? My android app (truxie) definitely has problems on the Ones I've seen.

Comment: We're using an HTC One X running 4.2.1 at work. That atleast, does not have the issue.

Comment: Ah - Then I blame HTC Marketing for their naming conventions.  The HTC One X is a 2012 model year phone, while their latest phone is called the HTC One.  So I'm not surprised to hear it works on a One X - Works on Evo as well (my personal phone).  Just not the HTC One.

Comment: @OMAK - 2 workarounds listed here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262324-Sencha-Messagebox-and-Overlay-Problems-on-HTC-One-Browser - but I haven't had a chance to test either, so I don't want to put them in as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer courtesy of appglu in Sencha forums:

in messagebox.js
set hideAnimation to null instead of:

```
hideAnimation: { type: 'popOut', duration: 250, easing: 'ease-out' },
```

This solution works on my new HTC One running my Sencha 2.2.1 app built in Cordova 3.0.

Further discussion here:  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262324-Sencha-Messagebox-and-Overlay-Problems-on-HTC-One-Browser

Comment: With Cordova 3.3 and Sencha 2.3.1 on the HTC One I had to also set the showAnimation to null as well.  Sencha says it is fixed as of 2.3 beta, but it isn't.